# Program that reads strings typed by user until nothing entered then prints strings in reverse order

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a program that allows a user to continue to type out strings until an empty string is entered. Then the program sorts through the strings and prints the string in depending order ( lexicographically ).

The string output should look something like this.

```
enter a string: the tree is nice and brown
output: tree the nice is brown and
```

I have tried to implement this code for myself however I have ran into a problem where it prints the code multiple times. see bellow code.

```
Enter string: the tree is nice and brown
Output:  tree Output:  the Output:  nice Output:  is Output:  brown Output:  and Enter string:
```

how can I fix my code to remove the Output: that continues to be printed after each word in the string. And also make the final enter new string print on a new line.
See bellow my final code.

```
s=input("Enter string: ")

while s!="":
    a=s.lower()
    b=a.split()
    b.sort(reverse=True)
    for i in b:
        answer=""
        answer+=i
        print("Output: ", answer, end=" ")
    s=input("Enter string: ")
```

Comment: You have a few issues, first you overwrite `answer` for every item in your list `b`. Thus the concatenation `answer+=i` does nothing (you could have written `answer=i` in the loop it would behave the same). Try to move the `answer=""` just before the for-loop first. Then your `print("Output...)` statement is executed for each word in your string, you want to only print `answer` once, not for all words, for this you need to put this print statement at the same level as the for-loop.

Comment: Also, you might want to add some spacing between each of your words. While doing a for-loop and concatenating each word into a string works, there is a useful function that exists in python to do exactly that: the [`"separator".join(your_list)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while s := input('Enter string: '):
    a=s.lower()
    b=a.split()
    b.sort(reverse=True)
    output = ("OUTPUT: \n" + " ".join(b))
    print(output)
```

Comment: hi this has fixed the problems and works perfectly although how would I be able to make the 2nd enter string appear on a new line and not next to the current string output ?

Comment: The character for "newline" is `\n`, if you put that in your `print()` statement it'll do it

Comment: Yep has fixed it, thank you all so much for helping me with this. I felt like I was getting close to the answer :)

Comment: Instead of two input statements why not *while s := input('Enter string: ')*. There's also a syntax error in the latest edit

Answer (score 0):

You could break this down to just two lines. Not necessarily very instructive but just for fun:

```
while s := input('Enter string: '):
    print('Output:\n'+' '.join(sorted(s.lower().split(), reverse=True)))
```

Answer (score -1):

You should probably collect all data first and the perform the operations you want on said data.

Left some comments on your code:

```py
s=input("Enter string: ")

while s!="":
    a=s.lower()
    b=a.split()
    b.sort(reverse=True)
    for i in b:               #Every time you input something new you also enter this for-loop
        answer=""             #This resets the variable every for-loop
        answer+=i             #This tries to concatenate a string i to the variable answer but since you reset the variable every loop you will never get anything else than i here
        print("Output: ", answer, end=" ")  #Does this run?
    s=input("Enter string: ")
```

"Correct" code:

```py
s=input("Enter string: ")

while s!="":

    # All the input data is split and all characters made lowercase and appended to wordlist variable
    a=s.lower()
    b=a.split()

    wordlist=[]
    for i in b:
        wordlist.append(i)

    # After splitting and making all characters lowercase sort the new list.
    wordlist.sort(reverse=True)

    # Concatenate the list into a new string
    answer=""
    for i in wordlist:
         answer+=" "+i

    #Print
    print("Output:"+answer+"\n")
    s=input("Enter string: ")
```